# XSLT Replace Id, Get Value of other node

Tags: xml, xslt, replace

Hey everyone i´m new to xml/xsl. I have following xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Miau.xsl"?>
<export xmlns="urn:VocabularyExport">

<categories>
    <category name="A" id="123" />
    <category name="B" id="456" />
</categories>

<vocables>
    <vocable categoryId="123" spanishWord="uno" engWord="one" id="45d0a344-785b-
4463-9877-5474c99fdc74" />
    <vocable categoryId="456" spanishWord="dos" engWord="two" id="03efffbb-1cbf-
44f9-a377-74da252daac0" />
</vocables>
</export>
```

to show it in a table, I have following (working) XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:l="urn:VocabularyExport">

<xsl:key name="category" match="category" use="@id" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
   <body>

    <h1>My Vocable Colletion</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Deutsches Wort</th>
        <th>Spanishes Wort</th>
        <th>CategoryId</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="l:export/l:vocables/l:vocable">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@germanWord"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@spanishWord"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@categoryId"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
     </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Instead of the `categoryId` i want to replace it with the category name (see node `categories`). Are the any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a good start for someone new to XML/XSLT, as you have added in handling for namespaces in your XSLT. However, you have missed this out in your key. It should be this

```
<xsl:key name="category" match="l:category" use="@id" />
```

Then, to get the category name, the expression you want is this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('category', @categoryId)/@name"/>
```

Comment: Oh, damn i already tried almost the same but my "match" was false :D thank u very much, mate ;)